# Php image show issue

Tags: php, mysql

I'm confused! Basically i've a form with 3 field ex: subject, image, message. **So**,

**(1)** If i upload image it's should be show image,
**(2)** if i don't upload image it's should be show just only subject and message no image box **and**
**(3)** if i don't upload image and if there are a youtube link in message box then it's should be show the vedio.  **

Following is my php code, but i can't solved the number 3 point! **

```
<?php 

if(empty($imgname))
{
echo '';
}
elseif(!empty($imgname))
{

echo "<span class='vedio'>";            
echo '<img src="' . $upload_path . '/' . $imgname . '" width="195" height="130" 
style=" background-color:f2f4f6;"  />'; 
    echo "</span>";
}
else
{
    echo "<span class='vedio'>";                
require_once("func.php");   
if (preg_match('%(?:youtube\.com/(?:[^/]+/.+/|(?:v|e(?:mbed)?)/|.*[?&]v=)|youtu\.be/)
    ([^"&?/ ]{11})%i', $msg, $match))
        {
            //    echo $video_id = $match[1];
        }       
        echo @get_youtube_embed($video_id = $match[1]);     
        echo "</span>";


}
?>
```

Any Idea or Solution that would be better for me.
Shibbir.

Comment: So.. what exactly happens when you try to implement number 3?

Comment: Well @Josh, it's didn't show any youtube vedio Now.

Comment: What is outputted? Anything? Errors? What is stored in `$imgname` or in `$msg` in your test case?

Comment: @Josh Please see http://www.favoritebd.com/morenews.php?currentpage=2 and http://www.favoritebd.com/morenews.php?currentpage=3, then you can understand what i told

Comment: Here you can see number 3 page there are youtube link (Subject:3d spider man) but it's didn't show any youtube vedio...

Comment: I provided an answer. I hope it provides insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll never get into your `else` statement because of your preceding `if` conditions. In ALL cases, `$imgname` will either be empty, or not empty.

To demonstrate further:

```
if (empty($imgname)) {
    // ... First condition
} else if (!empty($imgname)) {
    // ... Last possible condition
} else {
    // Will never reach here because $imgname will 
    // fall into one of the two of the above conditionals.
}
```

It's difficult to add to your code without full context, but it seems you may want to include the following after the above code (not with):

```
if(!empty($msg) && preg_match('%(?:youtube\.com/(?:[^/]+/.+/|(?:v|e(?:mbed)?)/|.*[?&]v=)|youtu\.be/)
([^"&?/ ]{11})%i', $msg, $match)) {

    require_once("func.php"); 
    echo "<span class='vedio'>"; 
    echo @get_youtube_embed($match[1]);     
    echo "</span>";
}
```